# Pico C programming: Make all projects use the USB port

Tags: c, pi-pico

I'm in the learning process for the RPi Pico using the C SDK. So far, the *interesting* examples I've followed output their results over the serial port. I've learned that ***some*** of the examples include a configuration to control whether the text (stdio) output is sent over the UART, or the USB, or both. For example, this configuration may be found in the following two lines in `~/pico/pico-examples/adc/onboard_temperature/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...
pico_enable_stdio_uart(onboard_temperature 0)
pico_enable_stdio_usb(onboard_temperature 1)
...
```

Apparently a `0` tells the compiler to *disable* the stdio channel (the uart in this case), and a `1` to *enable* the named channel (the usb). At this point I have neither the need or desire to use the uart. I want *all* of my programs to send their stdio over USB because it's much more convenient; my development system is a Macbook running Ubuntu 22.04.

However, for some reason, the examples seem to be inconsistent wrt designating stdio. For example, in `~/pico/pico-examples/adc/hello_adc/CMakeLists.txt`, there is no designation for uart or usb. I **assume** uart becomes the default for stdio, because I get nothing from this program until I add the following line to `~/pico/pico-examples/adc/hello_adc/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
pico_enable_stdio_usb(hello_adc 1)
```

##### And so finally - my question:

How do I change the ***default*** stdio selection for any program compiled on my system from uart to usb?